# Broken characters with Java/Postgres 14

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, resttemplate

I'm consuming this XML:

```
<SomePerson>
  <Number>1</Number>
  <Name>Талантбек</Name>
  <Surname>Ормонов</Surname>
  <Patronomic>Шарипжанович</Patronomic>
  <DataBirth>13.05.1987</DataBirth>
  <PlaceBirth>Ошская область, Фрунзенский район</PlaceBirth>
  <BasicInclusion>Приговор Аламудунского районного суда от 25.09.2017 г.</BasicInclusion>
  <CategoryPerson>экстремист</CategoryPerson>
  <DateInclusion>2018-05-21</DateInclusion>
</SomePerson>
```

as follows:

```
 final String response = new RestTemplateBuilder()
                    .build()
                    .getForObject("someURL", String.class);

// Do something with string response

final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class);

final Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

final JAXBElement<MyClass> sanctionList = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))), MyClass.class);
```

But all I see in the database:

[image]

and in my JSON api/frontend is:

```
Ð“ÑƒÐ»Ð·Ð¸Ð½Ð°  ÐšÐ°Ñ‡ÐºÑ‹Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð½Ð° ÐžÑ€Ð¾Ð·Ð±ÐµÐºÐ¾Ð²Ð°   
Ð¨Ð¾Ñ…Ð¾Ð±Ð¸Ð´Ð¸Ð½  Ð¨Ð°Ñ€Ð°Ð±Ð¸Ð´Ð¸Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð¸Ñ‡ ÐÑƒÑ€Ð¼Ð°Ñ‚Ð¾Ð²  
Ð¢Ð°Ð»Ð°Ð½Ñ‚Ð±ÐµÐº  Ð¨Ð°Ñ€Ð¸Ð¿Ð¶Ð°Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð¸Ñ‡ ÐžÑ€Ð¼Ð¾Ð½Ð¾Ð² 
Ð–Ð¸Ð±ÐµÐº  Ð­Ñ€ÐºÐ¸Ð½Ð±ÐµÐºÐ¾Ð²Ð½Ð° ÐžÐ¼ÑƒÑ€ÐºÑƒÐ»Ð¾Ð²Ð°
```

I've tried using `ru_RU.UTF-8` encoding for my Postgres database, and got the same result with `UTF-8`. What is causing this? Is this database related or the client/Java related or even Spring's `RestTemplate` related?

Comment: In my experience, in 9 out of 10 cases, this is caused by bad encoding in the HTTP transport (and RestTemplate uses HTTP)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This was one of such 9 cases. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by the bad encoding in HTTP transport, credit to [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) Fixed by:

```
 final String response = new RestTemplateBuilder()
                    .messageConverters(new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                    .build()
                    .getForObject("someURL", String.class);
```